# How to collect map from the Set of objects that has a list using Collectors.toMap

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have class Element with a list, my intended output is like this:
 `Map<String , List<Element>>`

```
{
    1 = [Element3, Element1],
    2 = [Element2, Element1],
    3 = [Element2, Element1], 4=[Element2]
}
```

And my input is set of element objects, I used `forEach` to get the desired outcome, but I'm looking for how to collect it using `collectors.toMap`. Any inputs are much appreciated

```
Set<Element> changes = new HashSet();

List<String> interesetList = new ArrayList();
interesetList.add("1");
interesetList.add("2");
interesetList.add("3");

Element element = new Element(interesetList);
changes.add(element);

interesetList = new ArrayList();
interesetList.add("2");
interesetList.add("3");
interesetList.add("4");

element = new Element(interesetList);
changes.add(element);

Map<String, List<Element>> collect2 = new HashMap();

changes.forEach(element -> {
    element.getInterestedList().forEach(tracker -> {
        collect2.compute(tracker, ( key , val) -> {
            List<Element> elementList = val == null ? new ArrayList<Element>() : val;
            elementList.add(Element);
            return elementList;
        }); 
    });
});


class Element {

    List<String> interestedList;
    static AtomicInteger sequencer = new AtomicInteger(0);
    String mName;
    public Element(List<String> aList) {
        interestedList = aList;
        mName = "Element" + sequencer.incrementAndGet();
    }
    public List<String> getInterestedList() {
        return interestedList;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) instead of `Collectors.toMap`, along with [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), which adapts a collector to another collector:

```
Map<String, List<Element>> result = changes.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getInterestedList().stream().map(t -> Map.entry(t, e)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

You need to use the `Stream.flatMap` method first and then pair the elements of the inner lists with the current `Element` instance. I did this via the new Java 9's `Map.entry(key, value)` method. If you're not on Java 9 yet, you could change it to `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value)`.

After flatmapping, we need to collect instances of `Map.Entry`. So I'm using `Collectors.groupingBy` to classify entries by key (where we had previously stored each element of the inner lists, aka what you call `tracker` in your code). Then, as we don't want to have instances of `List<Map.Entry<String, Element>>` as the values of the map, we need to transform each `Map.Entry<String, Element>` of the stream to just `Element` (that's why I'm using `Map.Entry::getValue` as the first argument of `Collectors.mapping`). We also need to specify a downstream collector (here `Collectors.toList()`), so that the outer `Collectors.groupingBy` collector knows where to place all the adapted elements of the stream that belong to each group.

---

A shorter and surely more efficient way to do the same (similar to your attempt) could be:

```
Map<String, List<Element>> result = new HashMap<>();
changes.forEach(e ->
    e.getInterestedList().forEach(t ->
        result.computeIfAbsent(t, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(e)));
```

This uses [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), which is a perfect fit for your use case.

Comment: Thanks alot for your comprehensive explanation and elegant solution . Very much helpful - Can you please share your blog so that i can follow you. Thank you again.

Comment: @PathbreakersINDIA it's [boundsofjava.com](http://boundsofjava.com), thanks for your support!